# how to redirect domain according to country IP address

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect, geolocation, geotargetting

I made a site it with some subdomains; according to the country's IP address the user is supposed to be automatically redirected to corresponding subdomain.

**Example :**

Main site is `abcd.com`

- Suppose some one from  **India** typed this url abcd.com,
- then the page redirects to `ind.abcd.com`

Comment: The GeoIP extension allows you to find the location of an IP address.
http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.geoip.php

Answer (score 30):

Download the geoPlugin class from:

[**http://www.geoplugin.com/_media/webservices/geoplugin.class.phps**](http://www.geoplugin.com/_media/webservices/geoplugin.class.phps)

(free lookup limit of 120 requests per minute and block for 1h if crossed the limit. the block will automatically remove 1 hour after the last time your server stopped sending more than 120 requests a minute)

Put a **index.php** file in your root folder:

```
<?php
require_once('geoplugin.class.php');
$geoplugin = new geoPlugin();
$geoplugin->locate();
// create a variable for the country code
$var_country_code = $geoplugin->countryCode;
// redirect based on country code:
if ($var_country_code == "AL") {
header('Location: http://sq.wikipedia.org/');
}
else if ($var_country_code == "NL") {
header('Location: http://nl.wikipedia.org/');
}
else {
header('Location: http://en.wikipedia.org/');
}
?>
```

Here is a list of country codes:

[**http://www.geoplugin.com/iso3166**](http://www.geoplugin.com/iso3166)

Comment: Correct me if i am wrong, but using this plugin, site become so slow becuase of this API call, we have dropped using this one.

Answer (score 27):

Check that you have the [mod_geoip](http://www.maxmind.com/app/mod_geoip) module (**GeoIP Extension**) installed on your server.

Then, tweak your `.htaccess` file accordingly :

```
GeoIPEnable On
GeoIPDBFile /path/to/GeoIP.dat

# Start Redirecting countries

# Canada
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{ENV:GEOIP_COUNTRY_CODE} ^CA$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://ca.abcd.com$1 [L]

# India
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{ENV:GEOIP_COUNTRY_CODE} ^IN$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://in.abcd.com$1 [L]

# etc etc etc...
```

---

And here's the [official documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.geoip.php).

Comment: How to install it via cpanel ?

Comment: Thanks simple and effective solution

Answer (score 22):

You could do this without `require_once('geoplugin.class.php');` like so:

```
<?php
$a = unserialize(file_get_contents('http://www.geoplugin.net/php.gp?ip='.$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']));
$countrycode= $a['geoplugin_countryCode'];
if ($countrycode=='US')
    header( 'Location: http://example1.com' ) ;
else 
    header( 'Location: http://example2.com' ) ;

?>
```

Comment: This worked like a charm. Thanks a lot. Simple and effective solution.

Comment: where do we have to add the above code?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a WordPress website, so its easy to use - (Geo Redirect plugin).  It's working like charm. Easy to use, easy to implement.

Comment: It seems to be a premium plugin. I found this one which is free: https://es.wordpress.org/plugins/iq-block-country/ needs you to download/upload an IPs database from maxmind.com though.