# How can I apply a URL Redirection from a country?

Tags: http, url, http-redirect, redirect

I live in USA. I have a website. I would like anyone that tries to view the website in Japan be redirected to a different webpage.

How can I go about doing this? Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with the GeoIP Extension if is installed on your server, look at this answer:

[how to redirect domain according to country IP address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9838344/how-to-redirect-domain-according-to-country-ip-address)