# How to redirect to file according to country wise

Tags: php

I am using different sites directories according to countries for my company like

> Getacho.com 
>   Getacho.com/pk/ 
>   Getacho.com/uk/ 
>   Getacho.com/ca/

I am using one script. As I am from pakistan when I open

> Getacho.com

I redirect to

> Getacho.com/pk

but the problem is when I open.

> Getacho.com/about.php

I do not redirect to

> Getacho.com/pk/about.php.

---

This is the script the code that does the first redirect:

```
<?php
require_once('geoplugin.class.php');
$geoplugin = new geoPlugin();
$geoplugin->locate();
// create a variable for the country code
$var_country_code = $geoplugin->countryCode;
// redirect based on country code:
if ($var_country_code == "US" OR $var_country_code == "UM") {
header('Location: http://www.getacho.com/');
}
elseif($var_country_code == "PK") {
header('Location: http://www.getacho.com/pk/');
}
elseif($var_country_code == "AE") {
header('Location: http://www.getacho.com/ae/');
}
elseif($var_country_code == "CA") {
header('Location: http://www.getacho.com/ca/');
}
elseif($var_country_code == "GB") {
header('Location: http://www.getacho.com/uk/');
}
elseif($var_country_code == "IN") {
header('Location: http://www.getacho.com/in/');
}
?>
```

Comment: I am using two files. like
http://getacho.com/geoplugin.class.php.txt
http://getacho.com/geoplugin.php.txt
you can see it<br/>

Comment: [how to redirect domain according to country IP address](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9838344/how-to-redirect-domain-according-to-country-ip-address)

Comment: What httpdeamon are you using? Apache? nginx? iis? lighttpd? Something else?

Comment: @simone nigro.  I have seen that. but mod_geoip is not installed in my server. im using simple hosting.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using Apache, you can use the server-variable `REQUEST_URI` to get the requested url. Then it is simply adding that to the url:

```
if ($var_country_code == "US" OR $var_country_code == "UM") {
  header( "Location: http://www.getacho.com{$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']}" );
} elseif($var_country_code == "PK") {
  header( "Location: http://www.getacho.com/pk{$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']}" );
} elseif( ... ) { 
  //etc
}
```