# How would you set up DNS to serve .com to US users and .co.uk to UK users

Tags: dns, web-hosting, globalization

I know it's possible to use DNS to direct traffic but where does the set up occur? Basically for a global website I would like users from each country to be served up my website from the nearest hosting that my site is running on.

Comment: is this for a specific sub-set of .com and .co.uk? Because there's no guarantee that all of the same domains exist in both. Depending on what you're actually trying to achieve, this may be best done at the client level. Otherwise, you're going to need to investigate geolocation and something that can modify the packet stream like an F5 GTM.

Comment: Hi, its for one site, just like amazon redirect to your location to .co.uk and .com. Although I think those might be different sites.

Comment: if you have to be able to transform the client submitted request, `amazon.com`, to `amazon.co.uk`, then you either have to be able to modify the request before it's passed out the LDNS to the world, override the host lookup (e.g, hosts file entry), or you could simply force the request thru a proxy and handle it there

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is check the geo-location of the user accessing your website and then in your code(assuming Php as the language) get the geo-location and redirect to the domain (.com for rest of the world or US) and (.co.uk for UK).

Comment: so redirect on the server-side? There's nothing can be done by the setting up the dns they first hit outside of our servers?

Comment: it works like this. when the user enters the link like .com then your server side code checks the request's origin and then you can get the geo-location of the request and identify where it is from and then accordingly redirect him if from other region or remain on .com if its us.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9838344/how-to-redirect-domain-according-to-country-ip-address check out this link.