# PHP header location redirect loop

Tags: php, loops, redirect

I found this php geo-redirect script [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9838344/how-to-redirect-domain-according-to-country-ip-address)

Here is the code:

```
<?php
require_once('geoplugin.class.php');
$geoplugin = new geoPlugin();
$geoplugin->locate();
// create a variable for the country code
$var_country_code = $geoplugin->countryCode;
// redirect based on country code:
if ($var_country_code == "US") {
header('Location: http://domain.com');
}
else if ($var_country_code == "NL") {
header('Location: http://domain.com/nl');
}
else if ($var_country_code == "FR") {
header('Location: http://domain.com/fr');
}
else {
header('Location: http://domain.com/int');
}
?>
```

I placed this code at the very beginning of my index.php.

The problem which I am getting and trying to solve is that when my IP is US based redirect script should redirect to itself and stay on home page. Instead I am getting some redirect loop and page doesn't load properly.

Comment: If you are in US, and you go to http://domain.com, the checker is comparing with US and redirecting you to  http://domain.com forever and ever. Try adding a location for us.  http://domain.com/us

Comment: But I want to redirect US to itself (domain.com) not create separate domain domain.com/us

Comment: Then, try checking if the user is hitting a different domain.. if($code=='US' && $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])

Answer (score 0):

**If location is US, then no need to redirect:**

```
<?php
require_once('geoplugin.class.php');
$geoplugin = new geoPlugin();
$geoplugin->locate();
// create a variable for the country code
$var_country_code = $geoplugin->countryCode;
// redirect based on country code:
if ($var_country_code == "US") {
   //header('Location: http://domain.com');
}
else if ($var_country_code == "NL") {
header('Location: http://domain.com/nl');
}
else if ($var_country_code == "FR") {
header('Location: http://domain.com/fr');
}
else {
header('Location: http://domain.com/int');
}
?>
```

Comment: @CarlosGonzález according to his question the redirection code is only written in main domain index page. Otherwise if every sub folder contain the same redirection code than the redirect loop will continues. Because as for your case **if you are visiting domain.com/fr and your location is FR?** than you cant visit **fr** folder. and it will be a redirect loop.

Comment: @Chayan Thx man! It actually works. Also thx Carlos for trying to help me. When I commented out that part you suggested, now I am able to redirect back to itself. Also I removed the code from index pages in fr/nl/int folders because it was making redirect loops. But this was before I posted my question here.

Comment: @MarkoLazar you can also put the redirection code in index pages of **fr/nl/int** folders. But you have to remove redirection for that folder. For example, In **fr** folder comment **header('Location: http://domain.com/fr');** this. That will remove redirection loop.

Comment: @Chayan Great! Will try that too.

Comment: @Chayan Ofc you can! Thx onca again!