# Multi country redirect working with google

Tags: wordpress, internationalization

I have company.com, us.company.com and ca.company.com.

I want the site to be displayed in Google as company.com but if the user is in the US and clicks company.com they are redirected to us.company.com.

The sites are WordPress and I have the redirects working using CloudFlare (see code below.

```
   <?php
      $country_code = $_SERVER["HTTP_CF_IPCOUNTRY"];

      if($country_code == 'CA') {
        header("Location: http://ca.company.com", true, 301);
        exit();
      }
      if($country_code == 'US') {
        header("Location: http://us.company.com", true, 301);
        exit();
      }
    ?>
```

Currently when searching Google for company.com, us.company.com comes up no matter the location of the user and company.com is nowhere to been seen.

I have Webmaster Tools set up for company.com and as of yesterday added us.company.com but not 100% sure if this is the way to go.

Any help/advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If you are open to use plugin then please check : http://codecanyon.net/item/wp-geoip-country-redirect/3589163

Comment: If you want to achieve by code then please check this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9838344/how-to-redirect-domain-according-to-country-ip-address

Comment: @HelpingHands Thanks, I'm happy to use either one as long as it works. As I mentioned, I do have the redirect working but Google doesn't seem to like it, with the options you have supplied will Google display the correct site?

Comment: So you mean if anyone from usa search your site using google then it should search site http://us.company.com?

Comment: @HelpingHands Yes. I am UK based and at the moment us.company.com is coming up when searching, I need it to be company.com in the UK, us.company.com in the USA etc..

Comment: I see then I think it is part of international targeting which you can do using google webmaster , please check : https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/62399?hl=en

Comment: I think you should ask it at : http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @HelpingHands I already have Geographic target set up via webmaster tools, I'll try on webmasters.stackexchange.com - thanks for your help :)

Comment: Question has been posted on http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/87579/multi-country-redirect-working-with-google

Comment: okay , just checked.

Answer (score 0):

A 301 permanent redirect will mean that Google will deem it to be permanent. It's probably better for you to substitute out 301 for 302 in this usecase:

> 301, "Moved Permanently"—recommended for SEO
>   302, "Found" or "Moved Temporarily"

[Redirects on Moz SEO](https://moz.com/learn/seo/redirection)

302 Redirects will not pass any of the ranking power over when Google Crawls the site.

You may also benefit by putting redirect/link back options in each of the regional sites, so people who end up in one by accident can find their way to the other.

Thanks