# country name based url redirection php .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, geolocation

I want if someone visit our website from United Kingdom so url should be www.myurl.com/uk and if someone from Canada so url should be www.myurl.com/ca 
if someone from usa so url should be www.myurl.com

i am able to fetch the country name from http://www.geoplugin.net/php.gp?ip=86.180.246.104 this api

for all the countries website look & feel will remain same only we will change the currency like default currency is USD but in uk it will be GBP etc

**Problems i am facing**

1. i need to know what code should i write in .htacess which will handle this script (when i don't have any specific file / folder with the name of "uk", "ca" etc)

2. i also want to keep country name in url with all other sub pages as well i.e. for United kingdom www.myurl.com/uk/contact-us , www.myurl.com/uk/about-us  and in Canada www.myurl.com/ca/contact-us  , www.myurl.com/ca/about-us

3. sometimes returning user directly hit to their desire page like www.myurl.com/uk/contact-us but this time if he is in Canada so url should be change as well to www.myurl.com/ca/contact-us

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to use mod_geoip and a similar question with solution was posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9838344/how-to-redirect-domain-according-to-country-ip-address)