# Country base redirection php code

Tags: php, redirect, header

I have three sub folder in my root UK, US, CA.

If any one open site in UK, he or she will be redirect on WWW.mks.com/UK

Also some in UK share this URL WWW.mks.com/UK/about-us to any one in Canada then in Canada that URL redirect on WWW.mks.com/ca/about-us.

Note I had WordPress sites.

Comment: so what do you want ??

Comment: I have used this 

$geoplugin = new geoPlugin();
$geoplugin->locate();
$country_code = $geoplugin->countryCode;
switch($country_code) {
case 'IN':
header('Location: http://mks/ca/');
exit; 
case 'GB':
header('Location: http://mks/uk/');
exit;  
}

Comment: You can use .htaccess. Check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9838344/how-to-redirect-domain-according-to-country-ip-address#answer-9838434

Comment: And what's the problem?

Comment: You can use : https://github.com/merajsiddiqui/Geography