# Rewrite sub folder dynamically with country code in WordPress using PHP

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, url, url-rewriting

I know this question has been asked so many times but I didn't find any working solution or example which I can use to fix my problem.

I have been working on a client site. There are two similar sites, one for their own country and second for other country's visitors.

Their main site hosted in the root of the server and second site hosted in the subfolder.

Now what I want is a dynamic URL rewrite for the second site which is hosted into a subfolder with the country code of the visiting user.

For e.g.

`http://example.com`

`http://example.com/subfolder/`

are the URLs.

I want this `http://example.com/subfolder/` to be changed into this `http://example.com/country_code/` where `country_code` is visitor country code in ISO format getting through PHP function.

So if the user is from **United States** the `subfolder` must be changed into `us`, the new URL should be now `http://example.com/us/`.

I want this to work for all types of pages, whether its a page, post, category, tag or author page.

So again, `http://example.com/subfolder/any-type-of-url/` => `http://example.com/country_code/any-type-of-url/`

Remember `country_code` is user/visitor country code in ISO format.

Let me know if someone needs more information on this. Thanks in Advance.

PS: I tried to achieve this using `add_rewrite_rule()` function available in WP.

Comment: how you get the country code in htaccess?

Comment: @SagarV I am not getting country code in `.htaccess` file, I have PHP function for it, btw I can get country code in `.htaccess` file too, see the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9838344/how-to-redirect-domain-according-to-country-ip-address)

Comment: Are they really going to host the same site for each seperate country? Why do you not use qTranslate X or WPML? You can do URL rewriting there exactly as described.

Comment: @Blackbam they are not hosting multiple sites, the site is designed to serve multiple country users. Read my question clearly, it says I want to rewrite subfolder with visitor country ISO code. If I use qTranslateX or WPML, it will not rewrite subfolder with country ISO code, it will just append to subfolder, like this /subfolder/in/. Btw translation plugins are not required in our case. I hope its clear now.

Comment: Folder name present in the hosting can be named anything, "subfolder" for example and the visitors should be able to access the site with their respective country codes. Example : http://example.com/us/blog & http://example.com/in/blog both these URLs will call http://example.com/subfolder/blog. Correct me If I am wrong ?

Comment: @PrakashRao you are right, do you have solution for this?

Comment: I think this code help you "RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule %{THE_REQUEST} subfolder/$1"

Comment: if both `http://example.com` and `http://example.com/subfolder/` are each wordpress install, then I think is impossible.. both has each own .htaccess. visiting `example.com/subfolder/` will use .htaccess of subfolder. But visiting `example.com/us/` will use .htaccess of `example.com`. And subfolder has `RewriteBase /subfolder/` on it's htaccess

Comment: @AvinashKumarSingh I need PHP solution not .htaccess solution.

Comment: http://example.com/us should be redirected to sub folder and main site should be intact. 
so you can write a simple url rewrite 
RewriteCondition ^(us|aus|en)(.*) /subfolder/$1
where us/aus/en are the country codes which suggests the directory to be picked

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by pretending rewrite rules through filter, based on user country ISO code. Please find code below.

```
function prepend_default_rewrite_rules( $rules ) {

// Prepare for new rules
$new_rules = [];

// Set up languages, except default one, get user language code
$user = get_current_user_id();  
$language_slugs = (array) get_user_meta($user->ID, 'country_code');

// Generate language slug regex
$languages_slug = '(?:' . implode( '/|', $language_slugs ) . '/)?';


// Set up the list of rules that don't need to be prefixed
$whitelist = [
    '^wp-json/?$',
    '^wp-json/(.*)?',
    '^index.php/wp-json/?$',
    '^index.php/wp-json/(.*)?'
];

// Set up the new rule for home page
$new_rules['(?:' . implode( '/|', $language_slugs ) . ')/?$'] = 'index.php';

// Loop through old rules and modify them
foreach ( $rules as $key => $rule ) {

    // Re-add those whitelisted rules without modification
    if ( in_array( $key, $whitelist ) ) {

        $new_rules[ $key ] = $rule;

    // Update rules starting with ^ symbol
    } elseif ( substr( $key, 0, 1 ) === '^' ) { 

        $new_rules[ $languages_slug . substr( $key, 1 ) ] = $rule;


    // Update other rules
    } else {

        $new_rules[ $languages_slug . $key ] = $rule;

    }
}


 // Return out new rules
 return $new_rules;
}
add_filter( 'rewrite_rules_array', 'prepend_default_rewrite_rules' );
```

Comment: Will it replace `subfolder` with user country code?

Comment: Not getting results what I supposed to get.

Answer (score 0):

.htaccess would be faster way to achieve this and won't have issue with users implemented full page cache too.

If you are using cloudflare on your website, you can use the following simple code in which we get country from cloudflare itself ;)

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on

#INDIA
RewriteCond %{HTTP:CF-IPCountry} ^IN$
RewriteRule !^in/ /in%{REQUEST_URI} [NC,NE,R,L]

#USA
RewriteCond %{HTTP:CF-IPCountry} ^US$
RewriteRule !^us/ /us%{REQUEST_URI} [NC,NE,R,L]

#THAILAND
RewriteCond %{HTTP:CF-IPCountry} ^TH$
RewriteRule !^th/ /th%{REQUEST_URI} [NC,NE,R,L]
```

This will replace

xyz.com/sg/random
to
xyz.com/us/random if the user is from USA.

In case you want to use GeoIP

```
GeoIPEnable On
GeoIPDBFile /path/to/GeoIP.dat

RewriteEngine on

#INDIA
RewriteCond %{ENV:GEOIP_COUNTRY_CODE} ^IN$
RewriteRule !^in/ /in%{REQUEST_URI} [NC,NE,R,L]

#USA
RewriteCond %{ENV:GEOIP_COUNTRY_CODE} ^US$
RewriteRule !^us/ /us%{REQUEST_URI} [NC,NE,R,L]

#THAILAND
RewriteCond %{ENV:GEOIP_COUNTRY_CODE} ^TH$
RewriteRule !^th/ /th%{REQUEST_URI} [NC,NE,R,L]
```

You can always add more countries as per your use case. In someone is still looking for a PHP code too, just let me know.

**For PHP based in Wordpress**

```
 //For fetching url eg. xyz.com/in/  from xyz.com/in/random-link/abc
 $current_url = home_url( add_query_arg( NULL, NULL ) );

 //For fetching random-link/abc
 $current_rel_url = str_replace( home_url(), "", $current_url );

 // I am using cloudflare country variable here , you can use any of your api or whatever method needed

 if( !empty($_SERVER["HTTP_CF_IPCOUNTRY"]) ) {
    $userCountry = $_SERVER["HTTP_CF_IPCOUNTRY"];
    exit( wp_safe_redirect( site_url() . $userCountry . $current_rel_url ) );
  }
```

You can modify redirect condition as per your use case.