# What is the best way to redirect user to sub-domain(au, nz etc) based on country?

Tags: javascript, php, apache, .htaccess, subdomain

I have a php based web application in which I want to redirect user to sub domain based on their country such as nz, au, in etc.

What is the best way to do that?

**Htaccess?
PHP?
JavaScript?**

How can I do with the above options?

Or you guys can suggest any other way as well!

Comment: For any kind of redirections, the first thing that handles the HTTP request is the web server. So for optimum performances the redirection should be done there (and specifically for redirections I highly recommend putting them in the Apache main configuration files, not `.htaccess`). Then it is the web application, so in your language but you need extra core (not outputting any content before the HTTP headers where the redirection happens). Javascript should be avoided if you want to support browsers disabling any javascript. You have also the HTML meta tag, but also to avoid.

Answer (score 1):

Please! check this out:

[geoPlugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9838344/how-to-redirect-domain-according-to-country-ip-address)

and there is more such way which is helpful.

**Edit**

Reference:

1. [geoPlugin class for PHP](https://www.geoplugin.com/_media/webservices/geoplugin.class.phps)
2. [list of geo country codes](https://www.geoplugin.com/iso3166)

Code:

```
<?php

$meta = unserialize(file_get_contents('http://www.geoplugin.net/php.gp? 
ip='.$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']));

if($meta['geoplugin_countryCode']=='IT') 
{
}
?>
```

For more details:

[PHP Geolocation Web Service](https://www.geoplugin.com/webservices/php)

Answer (score 0):

Something like this (Pseudo code!):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{ENV:GEOIP_COUNTRY_CODE}
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com/$1 [L]
```