# How do I setup .htaccess file to handle a specific redirect?

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I have a site that can be accessed in different countries which is represented in the URL.
For example if I go to `www.example.com/us` or `www.example.com/gb` I would be served different content.

My question now is if I can setup some redirects that will send all requests to each countries index page if the page requested does not exist. At the moment I only have a limited set of sub-pages so I can easily specify a list of all that should not be redirected.
So for example `www.example.com/us/test` (which does not exist) would be redirected to `www.example.com/us` but `www.example.com/us/service` (which exists) would not be redirected.

The thing here I'm not so sure about is how to keep the `/us` (country code part) in the redirect, since that is dynamic based on the country you visit (all countries are served from the same source, with different content based on the country code in the URL).
So `www.example.com/us/test` would be redirected to `www.example.com/us` and `www.example.com/gb/test` would be redirected to `www.example.com/gb` but if I have `/service` instead of `/test` it would not be redirected at all.

Note that I want to do this in the root .htaccess file, so it would be handled in just one place and it should work for any country code that I add in the future.

I don't have a good idea on where to start, can only find examples where you redirect to a specified path, not where the first part (country code) is dynamic based on the "input".

Comment: Probably this answer will help you - https://stackoverflow.com/a/9838434/4116955

Comment: Not really what I was looking for, since I do not want to force a user to a certain region/language, for example if you are abroad and want get some information it would be good if you could access your home region.