# How to redirect based on country

Tags: php, laravel, redirect

My primary domain name is **abcd.com**. But when a user from India comes into my site I want to redirect him to **in.abcd.com**. There are several solutions to this using  *[GeoPlugin](http://www.geoplugin.net)*. But the problem is site become so slow because of this API call. Is it possible to redirect other than this solution like using `.htaccess` or something else?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9838344/how-to-redirect-domain-according-to-country-ip-address , simillar issue , checkout the last answer that may help you

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to redirect domain according to country IP address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9838344/how-to-redirect-domain-according-to-country-ip-address)

Answer (score 1):

You need to install the mod_geoip module (GeoIP Extension) installed on your server. [link for mod_geoip](http://www.maxmind.com/app/mod_geoip)

Then, tweak your .htaccess file accordingly :

```
GeoIPEnable On
GeoIPDBFile /path/to/GeoIP.dat
# Start Redirecting countries
# Canada
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{ENV:GEOIP_COUNTRY_CODE} ^CA$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://ca.abcd.com$1 [L]
# India
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{ENV:GEOIP_COUNTRY_CODE} ^IN$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://in.abcd.com$1 [L]
# etc etc etc...
```

Comment: Can you suggest it with full .htaccess file. I'm confused how to write it in .htaccess of Laravel project.

Comment: you will find .htaccess on the root folder of your project and it will be hidden.
Then you need to open it and start editing it. do not touch already existing code there and start writing your code at the end of the file.

you just need to copy paste the code and replace the domain with your domain. just check the path your are defining is right or wrong GeoIPDBFile /path/to/GeoIP.dat

Comment: check the path for GeoIP.dat and give correct file in your file structure